# Post synthesis simulation wave forms not visible

Tags: verilog, synthesis, test-bench

I'm doing post synth simulation of a design for which I have testbench & verilog code and synthesis script .. which gives me verilog netlist files. 
I am able to see pre synthesis simulation - waveforms and the $monitor value dump on terminal. This same $monitor value dump also tells me that post synthesis simulation works fine.

BUT i am not able to see post synthesis waveforms

I'm dumping a .vcd file via my testbench for viewing the simulation waveforms via $monitor.

TOOL : Design Vision for synthesis 
       NCVerilog for compilation

```
`timescale 1ns  / 10 ps
module CLA_16_4_tb ();

reg  [15:0] A=0, B=0 ;
wire [15:0] Sum;
wire Cout;
reg  reset,clock;

initial begin : A_TB
           A = 0;
      #10  A = 16'h00FF;
      #30  A = 16'h0000;
      #30  A = 16'h80FF;
      #30  A = 16'h0000;
      #30  A = 16'h00FF;
      #30  A = 16'h0000;
      #30  A = 16'h1111;
    end

initial begin : B_TB
          B = 0;
      #10 B = 16'hFF01;
      #30 B = 16'h0000;
      #30 B = 16'h8080;
      #30 B = 16'h0000;
      #30 B = 16'hFF80;
      #30 B = 16'h0000;
      #30 B = 16'h2222;
    end

initial begin : reset_TB
           reset = 0; 
       #2  reset = 1;
       #5  reset = 0;
       #55  reset = 1;
       #5   reset = 0;
       #55  reset = 1;
       #5   reset = 0;
       #55  reset = 1;
       #5   reset = 0;
       #45 $finish;
    end

initial begin : clock_TB
            clock = 0;
        #5  clock = 1;
  forever   #5  clock = ~clock;
    end

CLA_16_4 U1 (A, B, Sum, Cout, clock, reset);

initial begin 
        $monitor("TIME :",$time,"   HEX VALUES : a_inp = %h    b_inp = %h    s_out = %h    c_out = %h",A,B,Sum,Cout);
    end

initial begin
        $dumpfile("CLA_16_4_tb.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,CLA_16_4_tb);
end 
endmodule
```

[image: $monitor terminal value dump]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing the +access+rwc in the ncverilog command line when you are running the post-synthesis netlist simulation and hence may not be seeing the signals in the waveform dump.